# Artifactory clear cache for remote repository

Tags: linux, devops, artifactory

Does enyone know how to clear cache of remote repository in Artifactory for loading artifacts (for example from maven repo) as well as in clean repository?

I tryed to find in Artifactory plugins, I found cleanup plugin but it cleans all repositories according description but I have to clean exact repo

Answer (score 0):

[Zap Cache](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-ZappingCaches) is the option available with the repository itself, by design, to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't have this feature in the Artifactory. I pro with trial period